# Covering lattice edges with Ls

Tags: combinatorics

I recall seeing (approximately this) problem in an old issue of "Quant", but I cannot recall anymore how it was solved:

Suppose that the edges of a $n\times n$ lattice are covered with Ls. Each L is a figure consisting of two adjacent lattice edges, and an L may point in any of the four directions: upwards left, upwards right, downwards left, downwards right. If all the lattice edges are covered with Ls and no two Ls overlap, prove that there are equally many Ls pointing upwards left as those pointing downwards right (and the same for upwards right and downwards left pointing Ls).

Any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: restrict you attention to a single diagonal line of lattice vertices, going from vertex on the upper border or left border and going down to the right. Show there are an equal number number upper-left Ls and downward right Ls whose corner is on that line.

Further hint:

> If you rotate the grid so this diagonal is horizontal, then one type of L looks like an open parenthesis, and the other like a closed parenthesis.